# Fetching GeoServer vector tiles in Mapbox GL is slow

Tags: geoserver, vector-tiles, mapbox-gl-js, pbf

I want to create a basemap with Mapbox GL and GeoServer and PostGIS (to store layers). I use GeoServer 2.18 and the latest version of Mapbox GL. There are about 20 layers in PostGIS. One layer is the country road layer. I cached the layer groups with mapbox vector format in GeoServer. The problem is the performance of my basemap. The basemap is slow while i zoom in - zoom out the map and it takes seconds to fetch the cached data.The cached data located in a folder. I try to show fewer features in the low zoom and more features in the higher zoom, but it doesn't work for me.

My URL address of the service is like this:

http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/test:basemap@EPSG%3A900913@pbf/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf

The status of my GeoServer is:

```
Locks   0   
Free locks
Connections 1   
Memory Usage    2.11 GB / 5.23 GB   
Free memory
JVM Version Red Hat, Inc.: 1.8.0_275 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM) 
Java Rendering Engine   sun.java2d.pisces.PiscesRenderingEngine 
Available Fonts GeoServer can access 280 different fonts. Full list of available fonts  
Native JAI  false   
Native JAI ImageIO  false   
JAI Maximum Memory  2.61 GB 
JAI Memory Usage    0 KB    
Free memory
JAI Memory Threshold    75% 
Number of JAI Tile Threads  7   
JAI Tile Thread Priority    5   
ThreadPoolExecutor Core Pool Size   5   
ThreadPoolExecutor Max Pool Size    10  
ThreadPoolExecutor Keep Alive Time (ms) 30000   
Update Sequence 937
```

I use this style:

```
[ 
 {
        "id": "sea",
        "type": "fill",
        "source": "nbmap",
        "source-layer": "countryboundary",


        "filter": ["==", "type", 2],
        "paint": {"fill-color": "#bedbec"}
      },
      {
        "id": "countrybound",
        "type": "fill",
        "source": "nbmap",
        "source-layer": "countrybondary",
        "filter": ["==", "type", 1],
        "paint": {"fill-color": "#fffef7"}
      },
      {
        "id": "provinceborder",
        "type": "line",
        "source": "nbmap",
        "source-layer": "provincebordersplit",

        "layout": {"visibility": "visible"},
        "paint": {
          "line-color": "#520c38",
          "line-width":1,
          "line-dasharray": [2, 1,1]

        }
      },
    {
        "id": "cityPoly",
        "type": "fill",
        "source": "nbmap",
        "source-layer": "cityPoly",
        "minzoom": 14,
        "maxzoom":22,
        "paint": {
          "fill-color": "#fafaf5",
          "fill-outline-color":"#f5ede1",
          "fill-opacity": 0.5
          

        },

      },




   
    {
      "id": "landcover_water_large",
      "type": "fill",
      "source": "nbmap",
      "source-layer": "landuselarge",
      "minzoom":6,
      "maxzoom":12,
      "filter": ["==", "fclass", "water"],
      "paint": {"fill-color": "#bedbec"}
    },
    {
      "id": "landcover_forest_large",
      "type": "fill",
      "source": "nbmap",
      "source-layer": "landuselarge",
      "minzoom":5,
      "maxzoom":14,
      "filter": ["==", "fclass", "forest"],
      "paint": {
        "fill-color": "#d3e3d8"
        
        }
    },
    {
      "id": "landcover_forest",
      "type": "fill",
      "source": "nbmap",
      "source-layer": "landuse",
      "minzoom":14,
      "filter": ["==", "fclass", "forest"],
      "paint": {
        "fill-color": "#a9d1b7"
        }
    },
    

    
   
    
    {
      "id": "park",
      "type": "fill",
      "source": "nbmap",
      "source-layer": "landuse",
      "minzoom":12,
      "filter": ["==", "fclass", "park"],
      "paint": {"fill-color": "#d6ecdb"}
    },

    {
      "id": "landuse_grass",
      "type": "fill",
      "source": "nbmap",
      "source-layer": "landuse",
      "minzoom":14,
      "filter": ["==", "fclass", "grass"],
      "paint": {"fill-color": "#cae3d1"}
    },

      {
        "id": "landcover_water",
        "type": "fill",
        "source": "nbmap",
        "source-layer": "landuse",
        "minzoom":12,
        "filter": ["==", "fclass", "water"],
        "paint": {"fill-color": "#bedbec"}
      },
    {
      "id": "waterway",
      "type": "line",
      "source": "nbmap",
      "source-layer": "waterway",
      "minzoom":14,
      "layout": {"visibility": "visible"},
      "paint": {
        "line-color": "#89b8f5"
        
      }
    },

      {
        "id": "parcelPoly",
        "type": "fill",
        "source": "nbmap",
        "source-layer": "cityparcel",
        "minzoom": 17,
        "maxzoom":22,
        "paint": {
          "fill-color": "#f7f5f2",
          "fill-outline-color":"#cfcfd1"


        },

      },


    {
      "id": "tunnel_minor",
      "type": "line",
      "source": "nbmap",
      "source-layer": "roadosm",
      "minzoom":16,
      "filter": [
        "all",
        ["==", "$type", "LineString"],
        ["==", "tunnel", "T"],
        ["in", "fclass", "service,","residential","unclassified"]
      ],
      "layout": {"line-cap": "round", "line-join": "miter"},
      "paint": {
        "line-color": "#bdb9b9",
       
        "line-width": {"base": 1.55, "stops": [[16, 3], [20, 30]]}
      }
    },

    {
      "id": "tunnel_major_casing",
      "type": "line",
      "source": "nbmap",
      "source-layer": "roadosm",
      "minzoom":11,
      "filter": [
        "all",
        ["==", "$type", "LineString"],
        ["==", "tunnel", "T"],
        

        ["in", "fclass", "primary", "secondary", "tertiary", "trunk","trunk_link","mainway","primary_link","secondary_link"]
      ],
      "layout": {"line-cap": "round", "line-join": "miter"},
      "paint": {
        "line-color": "#000000",
        
        "line-width": {"base": 1.4, "stops": [[11, 0.7], [20, 35]]},
        "line-dasharray": [0.3,0.7]
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "tunnel_major",
      "type": "line",
      "source": "nbmap",
      "source-layer": "roadosm",
      "minzoom":11,
      "filter": [
        "all",
        ["==", "$type", "LineString"],
        ["==", "tunnel", "T"],
        

        ["in", "fclass", "primary", "secondary", "tertiary", "trunk","trunk_link","mainway","primary_link","secondary_link"]
      ],
      "layout": {"line-cap": "round", "line-join": "miter"},
      "paint": {
        "line-color": "#e0e0e0",
        
        "line-width": {"base": 1.4, "stops": [[11, 0.5], [20, 33]]}
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "road_minor_casing",
      "type": "line",
      "source": "nbmap",
      "source-layer": "roadosm",
       "minzoom":14,
      "filter": [
        "all",
        ["==", "$type", "LineString"],
        ["in", "fclass",  "service","residential","unclassified"],
        ["==",  "tunnel", "F"],
    
  
      ],
      "layout": {"line-cap": "butt", "line-join": "round"},
      "paint": {
        "line-color": "#ababab",
        "line-width": {"base": 1.55, "stops": [[14,4], [20, 31]]}
      }
    },
   
    
    {
      "id": "road_minor",
      "type": "line",
      "source": "nbmap",
      "source-layer": "roadosm",
       "minzoom":14,
      "filter": [
        "all",
        ["==", "$type", "LineString"],
        ["in", "fclass",  "service","residential","unclassified"],
        ["==",  "tunnel", "F"],
 
 
      ],
      "layout": {"line-cap": "round", "line-join": "round"},
      "paint": {
        "line-color": "#ffffff",
        "line-width": {"base": 1.55, "stops": [[14,3], [20, 30]]}
      }
    }
   ,

      {
        "id": "road_primary_minzoom",
        "type": "line",
        "source": "nbmap",
        "source-layer": "roadosm",
        "minzoom":11,
        "maxzoom":12,
        "filter": [
          "all",
          ["==", "$type", "LineString"],
          ["in", "fclass",  "primary","primary_link","secondary","secondary_link"],
          ["==",  "tunnel", "F"],


        ],
        "layout": {"line-cap": "butt", "line-join": "round"},
        "paint": {
          "line-color": "#ababab",
          "line-width": {"base": 1.4, "stops": [[10,0.5]]}
        }
      },



    {
      "id": "road_primary_casing",
      "type": "line",
      "source": "nbmap",
      "source-layer": "roadosm",
      "minzoom":12,
      "filter": [
        "all",
        ["==", "$type", "LineString"],
        ["in", "fclass",  "primary","primary_link","secondary","secondary_link"],
        ["==",  "tunnel", "F"],
  
   
      ],
      "layout": {"line-cap": "butt", "line-join": "round"},
      "paint": {
        "line-color": "#ababab",
        "line-width": {"base": 1.4, "stops": [[12,2], [20, 31]]}
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "road_primary",
      "type": "line",
      "source": "nbmap",
      "source-layer": "roadosm",
      "minzoom":12,
      "filter": [
        "all",
        ["==", "$type", "LineString"],
        ["in", "fclass",  "primary","primary_link","secondary","secondary_link"],
        ["==",  "tunnel", "F"],
      
     
      ],
      "layout": {"line-cap": "round", "line-join": "round"},
      "paint": {
        "line-color": "#ffffff",
        "line-width": {"base": 1.4, "stops": [[12,1], [20, 30]]}
      }
    },

    {
      "id": "road_secondary_tertiary_casing",
      "type": "line",
      "source": "nbmap",
      "source-layer": "roadosm",
      "minzoom":13,
      "filter": [
        "all",
        ["==", "$type", "LineString"],
        ["in", "fclass",  "tertiary","tertiary_link"],
        ["==",  "tunnel", "F"],
   
     
      ],
      "layout": {"line-cap": "butt", "line-join": "round"},
      "paint": {
        "line-color": "#ababab",
        "line-width": {"base": 1.4, "stops": [[13, 3], [20, 22]]}
      }
    },
    

    {
      "id": "road_secondary_tertiary",
      "type": "line",
      "source": "nbmap",
      "source-layer": "roadosm",
      "minzoom":13,
      "filter": [
        "all",
        ["==", "$type", "LineString"],
        ["in", "fclass",  "tertiary","tertiary_link"],
        ["==", "tunnel", "F"]

      ],
      "layout": {"line-cap": "round", "line-join": "round"},
      "paint": {
        "line-color": "#ffffff",
        "line-width": {"base": 1.4, "stops": [[13, 2], [20, 21]]}
      }
    },
    
   
    {
      "id": "road_major_motorway_casing",
      "type": "line",
      "source": "nbmap",
      "source-layer": "trunk_motorway",
      "minzoom":11,
      "filter": [
        "all",
        ["==", "$type", "LineString"],
        // ["in", "fclass", "motorway","motorway_link","trunk","trunk_link"],
        ["==",  "tunnel", "F"],

   

      ],
      "layout": {"line-cap": "butt", "line-join": "round"},
      "paint": {
        "line-color": "#ababab",
        
        "line-width": {"base": 1.4, "stops": [[9, 2.5], [16, 20]]}
      }
    },
    
    {
      "id": "road_major_general",
      "type": "line",
      "source": "nbmap",
      "source-layer": "roadgenosm",
      "minzoom":7,
      "maxzoom":11,
    
      "paint": {
        "line-color": "#c9c7c7",
        
        "line-width": 0.7
      }
    },


    {
      "id": "road_major_motorway",
      "type": "line",
      "source": "nbmap",
      "source-layer": "trunk_motorway",
      "minzoom":11,
      "filter": [
        "all",
        ["==", "$type", "LineString"],
        // ["in", "fclass", "motorway","motorway_link","trunk","trunk_link"],
        ["==",  "tunnel", "F"],
 
    
      ],
      "layout": {"line-cap": "round", "line-join": "round"},
      "paint": {
        "line-color": "#d6d6d4",
        
        "line-width": {"base": 1.4, "stops": [[9, 1], [16, 19]]}
      }
    },
    
    {
      "id": "waterway-bridge",
      "type": "line",
      "source": "nbmap",
      "source-layer": "waterways",
      "minzoom":13,
     
     
      "paint": {
        "line-color": "#89b8f5",
        "line-width": 0.8
      }
    },
   
   
    {
      "id": "bridge_minor",
      "type": "line",
      "source": "nbmap",
      "source-layer": "roadosm",
      "minzoom":13,
      "filter": [
        "all",
        ["==", "$type", "LineString"],
        ["==", "bridge", "T"],
        ["in", "fclass", "service","residential","unclassified"]
      ],
      "layout": {"line-cap": "round", "line-join": "round"},
      "paint": {
        "line-color": "#e6d8d8",
        "line-width": {"base": 1.55, "stops": [[16, 0.25], [20, 30]]}
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "bridge_major",
      "type": "line",
      "source": "nbmap",
      "source-layer": "roadosm",
      "minzoom":13,
      "filter": [
        "all",
        ["==", "$type", "LineString"],
        ["==", "bridge", "T"],
        ["in", "fclass", "primary", "secondary", "tertiary", "trunk"]
      ],
      "layout": {"line-cap": "round", "line-join": "round"},
      "paint": {
        "line-color": "#bfaebf",
        "line-width": {"base": 1.4, "stops": [[6, 0.5], [20, 30]]},
      
      }
    },
   


    
    {
        "id": "hospital",
        "type": "fill",
        "source": "nbmap",
        "source-layer": "hospital",
      "minzoom":14,
      "maxzoom":18,
        "paint": {
          "fill-color": "#ffd6d6"

        }
      },
        

      

      {
            "id": "oneway",
            "type": "symbol",
            
            "source": "nbmap",
            "source-layer": "roadosm",
            "minzoom": 15,
            "filter": [
                "all",
                ["==", ["get", "oneway"], "F"],
                [
                    "step",
                    ["zoom"],
                    [
                        "match",
                        ["get", "fclass"],
                        [
                            "primary",
                            "secondary",
                            "tertiary",
                            "primary_link",
                            "secondary_link",
                            "tertiary_link",
                            "trunk",
                            "trunk_link",
                            "motorway",
                            "motorway_link"

                           
                        ],
                        true,
                        false
                    ],
                    15,
                    [
                        "match",
                        ["get", "fclass"],
                        [
                        "primary",
                            "secondary",
                            "tertiary",
                            "primary_link",
                            "secondary_link",
                            "tertiary_link",
                            "trunk",
                            "trunk_link",
                            "motorway",
                            "motorway_link",
                            "service",
                            "uncalssified"
                        ],
                        true,
                        false
                    ]
                ]
               
            ],
            "layout": {
                "symbol-placement": "line",
                "symbol-spacing": [
                    "interpolate",
                    ["linear"],
                    ["zoom"],
                    15,
                    150,
                    18,
                    300,
                    22,
                    600
                ],
                "icon-image": [
                    "step",
                    ["zoom"],
                    "oneway-small",
                    17,
                    [
                        "match",
                        ["get", "fclass"],
                        [
                        "secondary",
                            "tertiary",
                            "primary_link",
                            "secondary_link",
                            "tertiary_link",
                            "trunk",
                            "trunk_link",
                            "motorway",
                            "motorway_link",
                            "service",
                            "uncalssified"
                           
                        ],
                        "oneway-large",
                        "oneway-small"
                    ],
                    18,
                    "oneway-large"
                ],
                "icon-size": [
                    "interpolate",
                    ["exponential", 1.5],
                    ["zoom"],
                    15,
                    0.35,
                    20,
                    0.5
                ],
                "icon-rotation-alignment": "map"
            },
            "paint": {}
        },

       
        {
        "id": "stepfootway",
        "type": "line",

        "source": "nbmap",
        "source-layer": "roadosm",
        "minzoom":14,
      

        "filter": [
                "all",
               
                [
                    "match",
                    ["get", "fclass"],
                    ["step", "footway"],
                    true,
                    false
                ],
                
            ],
        "paint": {
          "line-width": [
                    "interpolate",
                    ["exponential", 1.5],
                    ["zoom"],
                  
                   
                    15,
                    0.7,
                  
                ],
          "line-color": "#ababab",
         
          "line-dasharray": [2, 2]
         

        }
      },

  {
        "id": "village_label",
        "type": "symbol",
        "source": "nbmap",
        "source-layer": "village",
        "minzoom":13,
        
    
      "paint":{
          "text-color":"#000000"
      },
        "layout": {

          "text-size":11,
         "text-padding":6,
          "text-field": ["coalesce", ["get", "name"]]

        }

      },



      {
      "id": "road_trunk_label",
      "type": "symbol",
      "source": "nbmap",
      "source-layer": "roadosm",
      "minzoom": 9,
      "filter": [
        "all",
      ["==", "$type", "LineString"],
      ["in", "fclass", "trunk", "trunk_link", "motorway", "motorway_link"]
      
      ],
      "layout": {
        "symbol-placement": "line",
        "text-field":  ["get", "name"],
        "text-rotation-alignment": "map",
        "text-size": {"base": 1.4, "stops": [[11, 13], [20, 18]]},
       
        "visibility": "visible"
      },
      "paint": {
        "text-color": "#000000",
        "text-halo-blur": 0,
        "text-halo-color": "hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.75)",
        "text-halo-width": 2
        
      }
    },


         {
        "id": "road_primary_label",
        "type": "symbol",
        "source": "nbmap",
        "source-layer": "roadosm",
        "minzoom": 11,
        "filter": [
          "all",
          ["==", "$type", "LineString"],
          ["in", "fclass", "primary", "primary_link"]

        ],
        "layout": {
          "symbol-placement": "line",
          "text-field":  ["get", "name"],
          "text-rotation-alignment": "map",
          "text-size": {"base": 1.4, "stops": [[11, 13], [20, 18]]},

          "visibility": "visible"
        },
        "paint": {
          "text-color": "#000000",
          "text-halo-blur": 0,
          "text-halo-color": "hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.75)",
          "text-halo-width": 2

        }
      },

      {
        "id": "road_secondary_label",
        "type": "symbol",
        "source": "nbmap",
        "source-layer": "roadosm",
        "minzoom": 13,
        "filter": [
          "all",
          ["==", "$type", "LineString"],
          ["in", "fclass", "secondary", "secondary_link","tertiary","tertiary_link"]

        ],
        "layout": {
          "symbol-placement": "line",
          "text-field":  ["get", "name"],
          "text-rotation-alignment": "map",
          "text-size": {"base": 1.4, "stops": [[11, 13], [20, 18]]},

          "visibility": "visible"
        },
        "paint": {
          "text-color": "#000000",
          "text-halo-blur": 0,
          "text-halo-color": "hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.75)",
          "text-halo-width": 2

        }
      },

      {
        "id": "road_minor_label",
        "type": "symbol",
        "source": "nbmap",
        "source-layer": "roadosm",
        "minzoom": 15,
        "filter": [
          "all",
          ["==", "$type", "LineString"],
          ["in", "fclass", "residential", "service","unclassified"]

        ],
        "layout": {
          "symbol-placement": "line",
          "text-field":  ["get", "name"],
          "text-rotation-alignment": "map",
          "text-size": {"base": 1.4, "stops": [[11, 13], [20, 18]]},

          "visibility": "visible"
        },
        "paint": {
          "text-color": "#000000",
          "text-halo-blur": 0,
          "text-halo-color": "hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.75)",
          "text-halo-width": 2

        }
      },


      {
      "id": "place_label_sea",
      "type": "symbol",
      "source": "nbmap",
      "source-layer": "countryprovinceseapt",

      "maxzoom": 13,
      "filter": [
        "all",

      ["==", "type", 2]
      
      ],
      "layout": {
        "text-field": ["get", "name"],
        "text-max-width": 10,
        "text-size": {"stops": [[3, 16], [8, 16]]}

      },
      "paint": {
        "text-color": "#161f4a",


   
      }
    }
    ,

    {
      "id": "place_label_province",
      "type": "symbol",
      "source": "nbmap",
      "source-layer": "countryprovinceseapt",

      "maxzoom": 15,
      "filter": [
        "all",

      ["==", "type", 1]

      ],
      "layout": {
        "text-field": ["get", "name"],
        "text-max-width": 10,
        "text-size": {"stops": [[3, 16], [8, 16]]}

      },
      "paint": {
        "text-color": "#000000",



      }
    },


    {
      "id": "place_label_largecity",
      "type": "symbol",
      "source": "nbmap",
      "source-layer": "countryprovinceseapt",
      "minzoom":7,
      "maxzoom":12,

      "filter": [
          "all",
          ["==", "type", 3],
          ["==", "ordercity",1]

        ],
      "layout": {
        "text-field": ["get", "name"],
        "text-offset": [0, 1.5],
        "text-max-width": 10,
        "text-size": {"stops": [[7, 14], [12, 14]]
       
      
      
      }
       
      
      },
      "paint": {
        "text-color": "#000000",
        


      }
    },

    {
      "id": "place_circle_largecity",
      "type": "circle",
      "source": "nbmap",
      "source-layer": "countryprovinceseapt",
      "minzoom":7,
      "maxzoom":12,

      "filter": [
          "all",
          ["==", "type", 3],
          ["==", "ordercity",1]

        ],
     
      "paint": {
        "circle-color": "#f04c41",
        "circle-stroke-color":"#000000",
        "circle-stroke-width":1,
        
        'circle-radius': {
'base': 1.75,
'stops': [
[7, 3],
[11, 5]
]


        }
        
      }
    },


    // all city


    {
      "id": "place_label_allcity",
      "type": "symbol",
      "source": "nbmap",
      "source-layer": "countryprovinceseapt",
      "minzoom":8,
      "maxzoom":13,

      "filter": [
          "all",
          ["==", "type", 3],
          ["!=", "ordercity",1]

        ],
      "layout": {
        "text-field": ["get", "name"],
        "text-offset": [0, 1.5],
        "text-max-width": 10,
        "text-size": {"stops": [[8, 12], [12, 12]]
       
      
      
      }
       
      
      },
      "paint": {
        "text-color": "#000000",
        


      }
    },

    {
      "id": "place_circle_allcity",
      "type": "circle",
      "source": "nbmap",
      "source-layer": "countryprovinceseapt",
      "minzoom":8,
      "maxzoom":13,
      

      "filter": [
          "all",
          ["==", "type", 3],
          ["!=", "ordercity",1]

        ],
     
      "paint": {
        "circle-color": "#f04c41",
        "circle-stroke-color":"#000000",
        "circle-stroke-width":1,
        
        'circle-radius': {
'base': 1.75,
'stops': [
[8, 2],
[11, 4]
]


        }
        
      }
    }
    
   ,
      {
        "id": "label_parcel",
        "type": "symbol",
        "source": "nbmap",
        "source-layer": "cityparcel",
        "minzoom":18,
        "filter": ["!=", "pelak_fa", "NULL"],

        "layout": {
          "text-field": ["get", "pelak_fa"],
          "text-max-width": 10,
          "text-size": {"stops": [[10, 12], [12, 12]]}



        },
        "paint": {
          "text-color": "#686869"



        }
      },
    
      {
        "id": "park_label",
        "type": "symbol",
        "source": "nbmap",
        "source-layer": "parkpoint_country",
        "minzoom":15,
        
    
      "paint":{
          "text-color":"#1d4225"
      },
        "layout": {

          "text-size":11,
         "text-padding":6,
          "text-field": ["coalesce", ["get", "name"]]

        }

      },
    
    
    
  ]
```

Comment: Vector tiles are pretty heavy - why not use a tiled WMS layer of the whole basemap and cache those.

Comment: @IanTurton because of the quality of vector data. vector data quality is better than wms .

Comment: that makes me think you are styling it wrong, or requesting it at the wrong DPI - since the end result is pixels I doubt there is any inherent advantage in quality of portrail

Comment: @IanTurton , Thanks. How can i request at the right DPI ? I updated my question. I added the style

Comment: see https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/vendor.html#format-options